# ScrolledComposite in Tabfolder

Tags: java, swt

I am struggling to get the scrollable area in tabfolder....don't know where i am going wrong...It would be great if i get some help on this...

```
    public void createCustomControl(Composite parent)
{
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());


    tabFolder = new TabFolder(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL |SWT.V_SCROLL);

    ScrolledComposite scroll = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scroll.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scroll.setExpandVertical(true);     
    GridData scrolledData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL
            | GridData.GRAB_VERTICAL);
    scroll.setLayoutData(scrolledData);

    Composite result = new Composite(scroll, SWT.NONE);
    GridData resultData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH |     GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL
            | GridData.GRAB_VERTICAL);
    result.setLayoutData(resultData);

    scroll.setContent(result);

    scroll.setMinSize(scroll.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `TabItem` and assign the `ScrolledComposite` to it by calling `setControl()`. Tab folder displays children only if they are assigned to tab items.

At the end of the code, add the following lines:

```
final TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
tabItem.setControl(scroll);
```